# Figuring out the launcher on this Android Studio Github project

Tags: java, android

Still a little bit new to Android studio and app development. On this project: https://github.com/watabou/pixel-dungeon, which file is acting as the MainActivity.java file? As in, which file is the main launcher of the application, how do you tell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The activity with the intent filters **android.intent.action.MAIN** and **android.intent.category.LAUNCHER** is the launcher for any app,

Just check which activity it has bellow intent filter that is launcher,

```
<intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

In that project PixelDungeon is the launcher activity.

Comment: Thank you. And one more question, why would the author of this game choose to extend Game in PixelDungeon.java as opposed to extending AppCompatActivity like the other apps I have seen?

Comment: He is extending this class https://github.com/watabou/PD-classes/blob/master/com/watabou/noosa/Game.java, and this Game.java class extends Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Your launcher activity is  defined in your android manifest (AndroidManifest.xml), it should look like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.Login_screen"
        android:label="Activity Validation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

For your case, if you want to edit your launcher activity just change ".activity.Login_screen" for the activity you want to display on launch. However, make sure that there are no duplicate definitions.

As you can see in your code:

```
<activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".PixelDungeon"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```